# How do you specify a unique prefix filtering for log streams in AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

If I enter

`ip-10-1-2-3` where it says `Filter loaded log streams or try prefix search` I get log streams like:

```
`ip-10-1-2-1`
`ip-10-1-2-2`
`ip-10-1-2-3`
```

and others.

How do I **just** get log streams prefixed with `ip-10-1-2-3`?

Comment: how about `strcontains` I am able to search logs using this query `filter @logStream = 'i-08637dda0d4'|fields @timestamp, @message, strcontains(@message, "ip-172-xx-xx-xx")| fields @timestamp, @message`